# Ionic overrides user-agent on ios

Tags: ios, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, jitsi-meet

I'm developing an cross-platform app for android and ios and I'm stuck with this problem about ionic rewriting ion user agent to ios 13.3.2 and safari 13.0.3. The problem is that I'm using an webrtc platform that don't support safari<14. I'm stuck on this for about a month and couldn't find any solution. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Someone in our team also faced this issue. They resolved it by passing a custom user agent. If you are trying from chrome's mobile view, you won't be able to do that.

Comment: I tried that in the intializeApp() method like this:
      
        if(this.platform.is('ios')){
        this.userAgent.set('Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 15_5 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.4 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1');
        }

But it didn't work. Any suggestions? Maybe I did something wrong.